# docker: how to make all devices available?

Tags: docker, usb

I am using a docker container to play around with some hardware. Some of them specifically need a `/dev/tty[something]`.

I know that I can always do `docker run --device=/dev/tty[something]`, but this is not very flexible as the specific device may not be plugged in at startup.

I read that alternatively, I can do `--privileged --volume="/dev/bus/usb:/dev/bus/usb:rw"` if I want to access a usb, but it turns out they specifically need the `/dev/tty[]`. Could I just do `--privileged --volume="/dev:/dev:rw"` to have everything available? Would this cause any problems with the host or the container?

**EDIT**:

I'm looking for a method where I can plug and play any USB device in the container.

Answer (score 4):

The `--privileged` flag is enough. It will give the container access to all host devices, as specified in [here](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/#runtime-privilege-and-linux-capabilities):

> a “privileged” container is given access to all devices

This can be verified by the following:

```
docker run --rm --privileged -it alpine ls /dev
```

Comment: This only works, if the USB was already plugged, when executing `docker run` and doesn't update for any USB device plugged in after.